# Как сжать полупрозрачное изображение для прохождения рекомендаций по Pagespeed?

Tags: изображения, pagespeed-insights, сжатие, pagespeed

При оптимизации сайта в **Pagespeed** получаю предупреждение:

> "Настройте подходящий размер изображений" - потенциальная экономия 0,46с

и

> "Используйте современные форматы изображений" - потенциальная экономия 0,3с

для одного изображения.

После экспериментов и сжатия различными сервисами, самым эффективным из которых показал себя [tinypng](https://tinypng.com/), картинка у меня занимает 66,6кб вместо 55кб рекомендуемыми гуглом.

Какие еще способы можно предпринять, чтобы добиться лучших показателей сжатия?

Comment: Гугл, скорее всего, намекает на излишний размер в пикселях

Comment: А современный формат - это webp

Comment: @KAGG Design  да, но он абсолютно не кроссбраузерный.. можно здесь что-то придумать?

Comment: Плагины, которые используют webp (или правила nginx/apache), определяют тип устройства и отдают webp, если устройство его поддерживает.